# Issue with clicking on calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, click

Here I'm stuck with figuring out why the calendar icon comes to be unclickable in most of the times. I'm curious as well If something in CSS or JS affect it. At the same time, as far as I know nothing has changed in the widget's source code and so why calendar comes to be unclickable is a good question. Please, assist me with fixing this issue.

[image]

*NB:* to see the form please use the switcher above and choose "Ж/Д билеты" (or rail tickets in English)

Strongly hope for your deep understanding and enough curiosity in this Friday evening :-).

Update 22:55 (MSK): Here is all the source code I can manage with. API JS is completely sourced from those who created the service of buying rail tickets online (just got in touch with them, they have no clue if they can fix this issue :xx):

```
    <script src="https://rwpartner.ru/partner/js/api/initapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">PoezdSearch.init({domainHome:"//poezd.ru/",restAPIUrl:"//poezd.ru/partners/api/",domainPartner:"//rwpartner.ru/partner/",partnet:"ruslanchik",newWindow:"1",FromStation:"Санкт-Петербург",ToStation:"",dateTo:"",customization:true,style:"//res.cloudinary.com/ruslanchik/raw/upload/v1453647850/go.ruslanchik.ru/css/traintickets.css"});
</script>
```

Update 23:07 (MSK): here is the URL: http://go.ruslanchik.ru/.

Comment: Please provide your JS code

Comment: @RLearnsR As Fernando says the above is only an image, we need code or at least a link to see what is happening.

Comment: Sirs, yes I did. Please look through the post above once again :-).

Comment: @RLearnsR The URL of this web page too please for debug.

Comment: @StJohn, respectively done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image for the calendar is missing for this particular calendar, shown by the console log below. They use at least three variants on that website. They will have to fix their code. At least the issue is not on your side.

```
GET http://rwpartner.ru/js/api/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Yes, I added my own PNG of the calendar just because their picture was completely not suitable for my website. If I understand you correctly, then I need to replace my own calendar PNG to the version that they provide me with? And if so it will work, will it?

Comment: It seems that their calendar API is still looking for the http://rwpartner.ru/js/api/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png file. Even if you replace it, you will have to change the call that looks for this to reference your new file. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, have a nice weekend :-).